# Code is printing only one multiple instead of 3

Tags: c++

I was writing a code which displayed first three multiples of an integer using functions. But here when I run this it shows only the first multiple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Defined first_three_multiples() here:
std::vector <int> first_three_multiples(int num) {
  std::vector <int> output;
  for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
    output.push_back(num*i);
    return output;
  }
}

int main() {
  for (int element : first_three_multiples(8)) {
    std::cout << element << "\n";
  }
}
```

Expected Output: `8 16 24`

Actual Output: `8`

Comment: you `return` inside the loop. voting to close as typo

Comment: once you fix your intendation you will see that `return output` is in the wrong place

Comment: @Chirag welcome to stackoverflow. An advice I would like to give you is to try to properly indent your code (using an IDE will do that automatically for you most of the time). In this case I did this for you. Having proper indentation can help you spot a lot of problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the `return` statement inside the `for` loop. It is advised to follow proper code indentations in order to avoid these kind of errors from happening again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> first_three_multiples(int num)
{
    std::vector<int> output;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        output.push_back(num * i);
        # you put a return statement here, which returns only 8
    }
    return output; # this would return all three values 
}
int main()
{

    for (int element : first_three_multiples(8)) {
        std::cout << element << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The error is the return sentence inside the for loop.

Comment: I didn't post the answer and the code is not mine. I just voted up your answer...

Answer (score 2):

Simple error

```
for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
 output.push_back(num*i);
 return output;
}
```

should be

```
for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
    output.push_back(num*i);
}
return output;
```

It pays to get your indentation right as it makes errors like this much easier to spot (and avoid in the first place).